# ggplot2 2 lines from data with 3 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have input data that looks like this:

```
            start_time              middle                 end RN
1: 2017-01-31 17:12:00 2017-01-31 17:40:00 2017-01-31 18:08:00  1
2: 2017-01-31 17:45:00 2017-01-31 19:03:00 2017-01-31 19:29:00  2
3: 2017-01-31 17:46:00 2017-01-31 17:48:00 2017-01-31 19:27:00  3
4: 2017-01-31 17:51:00 2017-01-31 18:40:00 2017-01-31 20:02:00  4
5: 2017-01-31 17:52:00 2017-01-31 19:52:00 2017-01-31 19:54:00  5
6: 2017-01-31 18:12:00 2017-01-31 18:46:00 2017-01-31 18:50:00  6
```

I want to ggplot this so that for each "RN" I want a line from start_time to middle, and another line from middle to end, and these lines should be different colours.

on the x axis I want time, and the y axis I want "RN"

How can I do this?

EDIT: here's what I tried

```
melted <- melt(input_data, measure.vars = c("start_time", "middle", "end"))

ggplot(melted[variable != "end"], aes(value,RN)) + geom_line(size=1, colour="red")
  + geom_line(data = melted[variable != "start_time"], size=2)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Usually people are a lot keener to help around here if you show some form of coding attempt. Otherwise this reads like "please write code for me".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't downvote, but to be honest, it's not entirely clear to me what you want to plot. The following is consistent with your *"I want to ggplot this so that for each "RN" i want a line from start_time to middle, and another line from middle to end, and these lines should be different colours."*

```
# Your sample data
df <- read.table(text =
    "start_time              middle                 end RN
1 '2017-01-31 17:12:00' '2017-01-31 17:40:00' '2017-01-31 18:08:00'  1
2 '2017-01-31 17:45:00' '2017-01-31 19:03:00' '2017-01-31 19:29:00'  2
3 '2017-01-31 17:46:00' '2017-01-31 17:48:00' '2017-01-31 19:27:00'  3
4 '2017-01-31 17:51:00' '2017-01-31 18:40:00' '2017-01-31 20:02:00'  4
5 '2017-01-31 17:52:00' '2017-01-31 19:52:00' '2017-01-31 19:54:00'  5
6 '2017-01-31 18:12:00' '2017-01-31 18:46:00' '2017-01-31 18:50:00'  6", 
header = T, row.names = 1)


require(lubridate);
require(tidyverse);

df %>%
    mutate(
        start_time = ymd_hms(start_time),
        middle1 = ymd_hms(middle),
        middle2 = ymd_hms(middle),
        end = ymd_hms(end),
        RN = as.factor(RN)) %>%
    select(-middle) %>%
    gather(Date, Time, c(1:2, 4:5)) %>%
    mutate(Stage = ifelse(Date == "start_time" | Date == "middle1", "start-middle", "middle-end")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = RN, col = Stage)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry my question was unclear, this is what I was looking for. I should have posted a fuller example. Thanks